# Laravel eloquent can't input data that field link have foreign key to some table

Tags: laravel

It so weird, i can input data from phpmyadmin. but i get this error when using eloquent.

> Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:
> a foreign key constraint fails (`laravel`.`medias`, CONSTRAINT
> `medias_typeid_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`TypeID`) REFERENCES
> `media_types` (`TypeID`)) (SQL: insert into `medias` (`Title`,
> `Synopsis`) values (doraemon, travel to the world))

json data

```
{
    "type_id": "3",
    "title": "doraemon",
    "synopsis": "travel to the world"
}
```

medias table

```
$table->mediumIncrements('MediaID');
$table->unsignedSmallInteger('TypeID')->default('0');
$table->string('Title', 255);
$table->text('Synopsis')->nullable();
$table->foreign('TypeID')->references('TypeID')->on('media_types');
$table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
$table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
```

media types table

```
Schema::create('media_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->smallIncrements('TypeID');
            $table->string('Typename', 100);
            $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
            $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
});

DB::table('media_types')->insert([
            ['TypeName' => 'Movie'],
            ['TypeName' => 'Tv show'],
            ['TypeName' => 'Comic'] 
]);
```

store function

```
Media::create([
            'TypeID'    => $request->type_id,
            'Title'     => $request->title,
            'Synopsis'  => $request->synopsis
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the following code

> ```php
> Media::create([
>     'TypeID'    => $request->type_id,
>     'Title'     => $request->title,
>     'Synopsis'  => $request->synopsis
> ]);
> ```

produces this SQL (according to your error message):

> ```
> insert into medias (Title, Synopsis) values (doraemon, travel to the world)
> ```

Then you probably don't have TypeID in your `$fillable` properties in the `Media` model

```php
class Media extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'TypeID',
        'Title',
        'Synopsis',
    ];
}
```

Also, unless you have a `media_types` row with TypeID = 0, that `->default(0)` in the `medias` migration is bound to cause more errors. If you want to make `medias.TypeID` optional, instead of `->default(0)` use `->nullable()`.

Comment: can u please see my next question. it happens same thing. i set already value in fillable 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66967542/cant-insert-data-eloquent-laravel